# Snap0.13.0 compile error

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-snap-framework

I try to install snap on a new ubuntu12.04 system (just installed ghc and haskell-paltform) with :
`cabal install snap`
but it failed because lens depend on vector-0.10.0.1, so I reinstall vector, and installed lens, and tried to install snap again but this time the error occured when compiling snaplet.auth:

```
[27 of 33] Compiling Snap.Snaplet.Auth.Handlers ( src/Snap/Snaplet/Auth/Handlers.hs,   dist/build/Snap/Snaplet/Auth/Handlers.o )
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
snap-0.13.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 9
```

I am not sure what to do this time.

```
cabal-install version 0.14.0
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1
```

--------------------------update -----------------------

I removed all the files in .cabal and .ghc and reinstall lens as I described above (though I have to install lens twice because the first try failed but the second try works), and 
then I installed snap-0.13.0.1 instead of snap, and it works this time.

Comment: Could you post versions of cabal, cabal-install, ghc, and the output of `cabal install snap -v3`?  Also, it looks like you might have a diamond dep issue - you could just blow away your local packages and try again from a clean system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You REALLY should upgrade your version of cabal-install.  0.14.0 is way out of date and sometimes old versions can generate install failures.  Also, when you blow away your local packages, don't delete the .cabal directory.  The vast majority of the time you only need to delete .ghc.

Also, please mark this question as resolved so it doesn't sit around as unanswered.  If you want, you can post your own answer and accept it.